# How to scan strings with spaces in cpp in a new line?

Tags: string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfEWF.png)3(no of cases)

hello world

a b c d

data structures and algorithms.

Let say above is the given input format.Each string starts in a new line.Can i know how to read in the above way in cpp.I tried with getline function.It didn't work.

Comment: Show us your code that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The getline method should work just fine. The following code works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s[3];
    getline(cin, s[0]);
    getline(cin, s[1]);
    getline(cin, s[2]);

    cout << s[0] << endl << s[1] << endl << s[2];
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

After your clarification, it seems that the problem is actually that the buffer is not being cleared properly. So just use `cin.ignore();` after `cin >> t;` 
Refer to the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >>t;
    cin.ignore(); // This should clear the input buffer
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i actually need to scan the integer also(3) .I mean number of testcases.The problem with getline is after i scan 't' (testcases) using... cin>>t,the compiler is expecting me to read the first string in the same line where i scanned 't' i.e; if i press enter after reading 't',the compiler is terminating the execution.By the way i am using online gdb cpp compiler.

Comment: Okay, the problem might be that when you use the `>>` operator it keeps the `'\n'` in the input buffer and as soon as it encounters the `getline`, the program just reads the `'\n'` from the buffer and moves on. Try clearing the buffer after `cin >>`.. If you need to know how to clear the input buffer, refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clearing-the-input-buffer-in-cc/).